# Converting LP into standard form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

$min$ $f(x)$
such that $a_i^Tx \le 1, i = 1,2,...,m$ and $|x_i| \le 1$

I know that first inequality can be easily converted into standard form by introducing slack variables but I am  a bit confused about what to do with the absolute value constraint, should it be equivalent to $-1 \le x \le 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear programming does not use $<$, it uses $\le$.

Yes, $|x_i| \le 1$ is equivalent to $x_i \le 1$ and $x_i \ge -1$ (i.e. $-x_i \le 1$).

Comment: Yes you are right, made the correction